# Reduce range selection by 5 points till specific row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table with two column compay id and revenueper. I want to fetch conpany list where revenueper is >50 if this criteria returns >=60 records then fine else reduce the criteria by 5 points and fetch where revenueper >50-5 and reduce the points by 5 till the count is >=60.

Please help.

Comment: Please share expected result,actual result and some data

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can do this using `TOP ... WITH TIES` together with an `ORDER BY` expression that rounds each `revenueper` value down to the nearest 5:

```
SELECT TOP 60 WITH TIES
companyid,revenueper
FROM someTable
ORDER BY (revenueper/5) desc
```

(Assuming revenueper is an integer type of some kind)

Comment: Revenueper is float value and i need atleat 60 recods it can be more than 60 but it should follow 5 percent downgrade in each try if not >= 60 then again -5

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
declare @threshold int = 50
declare @cnt int
declare @minNumberOfRows int = 60

select @cnt = COUNT(*) from MY_TABLE
where revenueper > @threshold

while @cnt < @minNumberOfRows
begin
    set @threshold -= 5
    select @cnt = COUNT(*) from MY_TABLE
    where revenueper > @threshold
end

select * from MY_TABLE
where revenueper > @threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your requirement, this is the best possible solution

```
  select a.* from Table a cross join(
  SELECT  revenue FROM Table order by revenue
  OFFSET 59 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) b where a.revenue>=b.revenue-b.revenue%5
```

let me know if it didn't worked